# stop displaying a footer navivation node from my web page using hmc or impex in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Can anyone please help me out in removing the footer navigation node from my page using hmc or impex? I am also looking for an appropriate source to know everything about WCMS so in case anyone knows about it then please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HMC,

1.click on WCMS.
 2.Select components.
 3.Search for Footer.
 4.Select staged version of footer component
 5.we have an attribute called navigationNodes.Edit the navigation node and save.

Answer (score 1):

Sree is correct. More specific, there could be property named  "Visible", you can use it. More information, you can find here: [Hybris Wiki](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/accdoc/WCMS+Components)